# Parsing a String variable and insert values in a Map

Tags: java, android

I have the string below that i got from opening a file containing a list of US of states an their capitals

```
    String text = "US_states"; //text file with US States and capitols

    byte[] buffer = null;

    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = getAssets().open(text);
        int size = is.available(); //size of the file in bytes
        buffer = new byte[size]; //declare the size of the byte array with size of the file
        is.read(buffer); //read file
        is.close(); //close file

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String str_data = new String(buffer); // Store text file data in the string variable
    }
```

Now I'd like to parse this string and insert it into a map objet
 Map m = new HashMap();
but I am not sure how to parse/split the various elements...

State                   Capital
----------------        ---------------
Alabama                 Montgomery
Alaska                  Juneau
Arizona                 Phoenix
Arkansas                Little Rock
California              Sacramento
Colorado                Denver
Connecticut             Hartford
Delaware                Dover
Florida                 Tallahassee
Georgia                 Atlanta
Hawaii                  Honolulu
Idaho                   Boise
Illinois                Springfield
Indiana                 Indianapolis
Iowa                    Des Moines
Kansas                  Topeka
Kentucky                Frankfort
Louisiana               Baton Rouge
Maine                   Augusta
Maryland                Annapolis
Massachusetts           Boston
Michigan                Lansing
Minnesota               Saint Paul
Mississippi             Jackson
Missouri                Jefferson City
Montana                 Helena
Nebraska                Lincoln
Nevada                  Carson City
New Hampshire           Concord
New Jersey              Trenton
New Mexico              Santa Fe
New York                Albany
North Carolina          Raleigh
North Dakota            Bismarck
Ohio                    Columbus
Oklahoma                Oklahoma City
Oregon                  Salem
Pennsylvania            Harrisburg
Rhode Island            Providence
South Carolina          Columbia
South Dakota            Pierre
Tennessee               Nashville
Texas                   Austin
Utah                    Salt Lake City
Vermont                 Montpelier
Virginia                Richmond
Washington              Olympia
West Virginia           Charleston
Wisconsin               Madison
Wyoming                 Cheyenne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write an efficient algorithm on an highly disorganised data and expect results. Data organisation is as important as any data processing algorithm.

Step 1 should be organising your data. Basically, my understanding is, when you work on parsing any plain text based data, the below two things should/could be kept in mind in order to help your parsing algorithm work effectively.

1. **Delimiter** - A character which would be used as boundary to separate two consecutive values. For e.g. comma(,)

For e.g. **Alabama, Montgomery, Louisiana, Baton Rouge,**

2. **Field Qualifier (Optional)** - A valid character that envelopes any multi-word values of which some special characters like space or the delimiter itself are part of value itself just so you avoid unintended results. For e.g. *Baton Rouge* doesn't end up being *Baton, Rouge*

With Qualifier you can have

**"Alabama", "Montgomery", "Louisiana", "Baton Rouge"**

Once you have your data in that format, you can simply apply String's `split` method and can proceed from there.

One word of caution, when you make use of `String` as a key, both *Alabama* and *alabama* could be used as two separate keys. You better have the strings saved as Uppercase or Lowercase as keys so as to have valid/unique identity as keys.

As for the HashMap and how to use it I hope this [Map Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here data displayed (state and capital) are not displayed according to a regular pattern. The single thing which separates them is a whitespace but it is not enough because some sates and some capitals use whitespaces (ex: South Carolina :2, Salt Lake City :3) 

So, you cannot use a simple regex to parse data.
If you want to handle that data, you should have a separator char between unitary data (`;` for example) which is not a whitespace char since as explained already used by some states and capitals.

With that, you are stick...

Answer (score 0):

Step (1) : Split the string (which contains the capitals & states) with white space (delimiter)

Step (2):  Collect the Split result into an array object

Step (3) : Iterate over the array to collect States & Capitals the `HashMap`

```
  Map<String, String> capitals = new HashMap<>();
  //Split using the delimiter " " to the all elements
  String[] stateCapsArray = str_data.split(" ");
  //Iterate over the array
  for(int i=0;i<stateCapsArray.length-1;i++) {
  //Skip each other element as we are collecting 2 elements at a time
    if(i%2 == 0) {
       String state = stateCapsArray[i];
       String capital = stateCapsArray[i+1];
       capitals.put(state, capital);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. As per comments from others, I formated the input file to use ":" as a delimiter and use your code to collect the state/capital. Works great